# Best python library for training using Hidden Marov model with Gaussian Mixture

Tags: python, markov-process, markov-hidden-model, expectation-maximization

I would like to train my data using `HMM- GMM (Baum Welch approach with gaussian Mixture)` to find the best parameters suited for my data.

**Note** : My data is continuous and not discrete.

I tried with `hmmlearn from scikit learn`, but i believe it is not supporting continuous HMM-GMM model, but i tried with discrete data, it woks fine.

I tried to use `pomegranate`, but i cannot able to understand the document, also i am not sure whether it uses GMM to fit my data.

I try to install `hmms` libraray, but i receive an error while installing,

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\eponr\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\hmms\

```
Collecting hmms
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/e4/c070c44ec8a391f6d5501316d1ed7615058f1fd365ff4ed65c9636d0bf62/hmms-0.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\eponr\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\hmms\setup.py", line 22, in <module>
        ext_modules=cythonize(glob.glob('hmms/*.pyx'), language_level=3, include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]),
      File "C:\Users\eponr\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 955, in cythonize
        c_options = CompilationOptions(**options)
      File "C:\Users\eponr\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py", line 563, in __init__
        raise ValueError(message)
    ValueError: got unknown compilation option, please remove: include_dirs
```

**Kindly suggest some libraries in python, which describes my problem ?**

Comment: have you tried this.?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520619/extra-compile-args-in-cython

Comment: *seqlearn https://larsmans.github.io/seqlearn/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

The GMMHMM model from [hmmlearn](https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn) supports continious-valued data.